# "My concern is with the rhythms of nature I work inside out, like nature."

Tags: meaning

> My concern is with the rhythms of nature I work inside out, like
> nature

Jackson Pollock

Is the word "with" in the quote necessary? Would the quote change its meaning without the word "with"?

Comment: It's the difference between being _concerned about_ and being _concerned with_.

Comment: English speaking poets, painters, sculptors, playwrights, and photographers all use English to describe their works.  I would suggest artists' descriptions of their works are not useful texts with which to learn the language.  And no, *with* is not necessary.

Comment: Where are the literalists, claiming that rhythms can't be worked, inside or out?

Comment: @EllieK Your advice is sound. Some creative artists of the sort you list have a tendency to pretentious description of what they do, wander into realms of unsubstantiated metaphor, reveal inflated notions of their own significance, and consequently they produce prose that is only weakly related to common usage. They are not good models for a learner.